# Почему в двух почти одинаковых C# проектах ContentRootPath отличаются?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

У меня есть 2 прокта:

`Project1/Program.cs`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var rootPath = builder.Environment.ContentRootPath;
...
```

`Project2/Program.cs`:

```
var builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder();
var rootPath = builder.Environment.ContentRootPath;
...
```

Почему в первом проекте `rootPath` - это путь к директории проекта `.../Project1`, а во втором - это путь к `.dll` `.../Project2/bin/Debug/net7.0`?

Вроде всё проверил - `appsettings.json` файлы одинаковые, `launchSettings.json` - тоже. Делаю в райдере, проверил конфигурации запуска - тоже одинаковые. `.csproj` файлы тоже почти одинаковые - у первого проекта `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">`, у второго `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">` (ну и некоторые другие строки).

Как мне сделать так, чтобы во втором случае тоже был путь до директории проекта?

Замена `Host.CreateApplicationBuilder` на `WebApplication.CreateBuilder` помогает. Но насколько это правильное решение, если мне не нужен веб?

Comment: Зачем вам тогда ASP, если не нужен веб..? А так, я думаю вам нужно прочитать [это](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/compatibility/extensions/7.0/contentrootpath-hosted-app).